# Shell script getting 'permission denied' despite using umask 000 before command

Tags: debian, shell, scripting, compiling

I have a shell script (build.sh) that ends by attempting to copy some files into a new directory. However it says:

> mkdir: cannot create directory
>   ‘/files/ondisk/shared//comp/auto/bleeding-1169-b28d31a’: Permission
>   denied

when running the script.

The command is:

```
( umask 000; mkdir -p "${BASE}/${TARGET}" ) || exit -1
( umask 000; cp -r ${STORE} "${BASE}/${TARGET}" ) || exit -1
```

Does umask 000 not ensure that I am able to write to this location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That double-slash in the pathname looks odd.  Perhaps you have no permission to write the `${BASE}`, which might be `/files/ondisk/shared`.  The `umask` value is irrelevant, because it only affects the permissions of the directories and files which `mkdir` and `cp` create — not the permissions of the existing directory into which you are copying.

Comment: Thank you. I did indeed not have permission for all users in the folder in which I attempted to mkdir (in the script). 
I changed permissions for all users for that folder to rwx, and then it worked.